# Finding a lower bound for the expression $\ln^k(n)$

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Problem:
Assume that $k \geq 1$ and $\epsilon \geq 0$, is $\ln^k(n) \in$ $\Omega( n^\epsilon)$?

Answer:

In the special case of $\epsilon = 0$, I claim the answer is no. I suspect the person who wrote this
problem meant to write: assuming $\epsilon > 0$.

I claim that if we differentiate $\log^k(n)$, k times then we get an expression with $n^{-k}$ in it. If
we differentiate $n^{e}$  k times then we get an expression with $n^{\epsilon- 2}$ in it. Let me illustrate
this with an example. Suppose I pick $k = 2$. Then if I differentiate the first expression twice, I get:
$$ \frac{ 2 - 2 \ln(x) }{x^2} $$
When I differentiate the second expression twice, I get:
$$ \epsilon ( \epsilon - 1 ) n ^ { \epsilon - 2 } $$
Hence, I claim the answer is no. Do I have this right?

Comment: Are you sure that $\ln^k n$ denots the $k$-th derivative of $\ln n$? This would be usually written as $\ln^{(k)} n$. What's probably meant by $\ln^k n$ is $(\ln n)^k$. This is a common abuse of notation. Another, less common, option would be $\ln^k n = \underbrace{\ln \ln \dots \ln}_{k \text{ times}}\, n$.

Comment: @Steven When I wrote $\ln^k(n)$, I meant $(\ln(n))^k$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\log^k n$ most likely stands for $(\ln n)^k$ (this is a common abuse of notation).
In this case the claim is trivially when $\varepsilon=0$ true since $n^\varepsilon=1$ and $\ln^k n = \Omega(1)$.

For constant $\varepsilon>0$ and $k \ge 1$ you have:
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\ln^k n}{n^\varepsilon} =
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \frac{\ln n}{n^\frac{\varepsilon}{k}} \right)^k = 
\left( \lim_{n \to +\infty}  \frac{\ln n}{n^\frac{\varepsilon}{k}} \right)^k =
\left( \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{k} \cdot n^{\frac{\varepsilon}{k}-1}}\right)^k
= \left( \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{k}{\varepsilon n^\frac{\varepsilon}{k}} \right)^k
 = 0,
$$

showing that $\ln^k n = o(n^\varepsilon)$, and hence that the claim is false.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that $\ln(n)=o(n^{\epsilon'})$ for any $\epsilon'>0$. Now, fix some $k$, and define $\epsilon':=\frac{\epsilon}{k}$.

From the multiplicative rule of the small-o (or equivalently, the multiplicative rule of limits), since $k\in \mathbb{N}$, we get: $\ln^k(n)={o(n^{\epsilon'})}^k=o({(n^{\epsilon'})}^k)=o(n^{k\epsilon'})=o(n^\epsilon)$.

Thus $\ln^k(n)=o(n^\epsilon)$, which means that $\ln^k=\Omega(n^\epsilon)$ **is a false statement**, for any $\epsilon$.

Comment: This argument is not correct in the sense that to pass from the statement in the first line to the statement in the second line the fact that $x\mapsto x^k$ is monotonically increasing is not enough (it is not all that is being used).

Comment: You are right. I should have said instead "the multiplicative rule of the small-o (equivalently, limits)"